# Screen flickering/janking while rendering a grid of cards in react

Tags: reactjs, performance, scroll, semantic-ui-react

I have an `eCommerce` site where there are product cards displayed in a grid. I am using `react-semantic-ui` grids and cards. Even when there are few cards, ex: 5-6 If I scroll too fast the screen flickers and slows down. The components disappear and when I stop scrolling they reappear but there's a visible lag. This is even more apparent on mobiles.

The page in question is [here](https://biggbee.com/explore)

I tried `react-window` and `react-virtualized` they don't seem to do much and overcomplicates the whole thing. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Could you post an example, so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: If you can just go to the link I gave, from a phone you'll see it. Just scroll and you'll see the lag.

Comment: I don't have any laggs on this site. The only thing I can see is, that loading the images is very slow.